# MEAN stack mongoDB example (mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I'm currently writing the backend of a MEAN stack application with mongoose.
Basically I want a database called "Simulations". In this datebase, I want to store one collection per user who is logged in to the frontend like "user1". In those collections, there are many documents but all of the same structure.

Anyone can give me a hint or a link on how to do that? I google arround since hours but all the examples do not match my application. I made experiments with the one-model-per-collection method as in every tutorial. But how to add them on runtime when a new user signs up?

I have not quite looked through yet...

My actual code

```
// simulation.route.js

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const simulationRoutes = express.Router();

let Simulation = require('../models/simulation');

// Defined get data(index or listing) route
simulationRoutes.route('/').get(function (req, res) {
  Simulation.find(function (err, simulations){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    else {
      res.json(simulations);
    }
  });
});
```

```js
//nodeServerModel.js

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var Simulation = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Enter the name of the simulation'
  },
  comment: {
    type: String,
  },
  ...
}
);

const Simulations = mongoose.connection.useDb('Simulations');

module.exports = Simulations.model('User', Simulation);
```

So, I think what I want, is to pass over the user name with the URL and then require the appropriate model. But I can't do all the models for every user now, because there are no users yet.

Thanks for the help and the patience with a total beginner in backend programming :)

Comment: Maybe you should share your code (the one that couldn't add to runtime) and then we can guide you from there?

Comment: @Sashi I just wanted some hints for further studiyng this topic. But you are right, this is maybe the better solution. I tried to break my code down to the absolute minimum which is needed for the mongoDB part

Comment: Okay great :) Thanks for providing your code. Just to be clear, what do you mean by add a new collection per user? Are you going to create a new collection for every user you have?

Comment: Here are some useful links: https://medium.com/@dinyangetoh/how-to-build-simple-restful-api-with-nodejs-expressjs-and-mongodb-99348012925d, https://www.callicoder.com/node-js-express-mongodb-restful-crud-api-tutorial/

Comment: @Sashi yes exactly. So basically in the frontend you can login with your username. In a dropdown menu I want to list all the stored simulations of this user. Therefore I want a database called "Simulations" with a collection for each user. In there you can find all the stored simulations of the specific user.